# Java get not containing Objects of List a in List b

Tags: java, list

Is there a better way of doing this - its such a boilderplate code.
I use Java 8 and I would do this with streams - but I would need some help doing this. I have tried it with ...removeIf() but it did not work.

```
final List<CalendarEventUserConnection> calendarEventUserConnectionsToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final CalendarEventUserConnection existingCalendarEventUserConnection : existingCalendarEventUserConnections) {
        boolean contains = false;
        for (final CalendarEventUserConnection newCalendarEventUserConnection : calendarEventUserConnections) {
            if (newCalendarEventUserConnection.getId() != null
                && newCalendarEventUserConnection.getId().equals(existingCalendarEventUserConnection.getId())) {
                contains = true;
            }
        }
        if (contains == false) {
            calendarEventUserConnectionsToDelete.add(existingCalendarEventUserConnection);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a better way of asking this question? It contains almost no information.

Comment: doing this -  what is "this"? If you are unable to explain, we sure won't be

Comment: Yes.  Don't use 20+ character variable names.  And don't use `== false`.  That's what the `!` operator is for.

Comment: @StephenC: '== false' is legit. '!= true' adds a little more complexity to it. At least it is a concern of style.

Comment: @Chris311 `contains == false` --> `!contains`

Comment: @Chris311 - Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/5382/java-pitfalls-language-syntax/20112/pitfall-using-to-test-a-boolean#t=2017022816092415446.  It explains why it is not simply a matter of clumsiness.

Comment: Didn't notice you were adressing this problem. Good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can streamify it up. It looks like you're filtering a list to see if anything in another list matches it, and collect the results in another list.

So you can use [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-), [`noneMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-).

```
final List<CalendarEventUserConnection> toDelete = existingCalendarEventUserConnections.stream()
    .filter(c -> calendarEventUserConnections.stream()
                  .map(CalendarEventUserConnection::getId)
                  .noneMatch(id -> id!=null && id.equals(c.getId())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @kio21 You are correct. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain all Objects that are on listA and not on listB

```
public static <T> List<T> aNotB(List<T> listA, List<T> listB) {

    List<T> result = new ArrayList(listA);
    result.removeAll(listB);

    return result;
}
```

*This only works if the `equals` method of `T` is correctly implemented...*

Comment: The result depends on how `equals` is implemented, which may be different from the logic in the question.

Comment: but the question is VERY open in that regard... and others... and I assumed that `equals` is correctly implemented.

Comment: The question compares the *ids* of the objects, which means that the actual object may not even have `equals` overridden.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - maybe not, maybe it does - OP does not explain what s/he really needs

Comment: and BTW, its not that strange to assume that two objects with the same ID *must* be considered as equal

Answer (score 1):

Your own search is O(NxM), where N is the number of elements in one list, and M in the other.

I suggest collecting all the IDs in the `calendarEventUserConnections` into a set.

Then you could collect all the elements in `existingCalendarEventUserConnections` whose ID is in that set into your deletion list.

Assuming your IDs are strings, this would be something like:

```
Set<String> idsToDelete = calendarEventUserConnections.stream()
                          .map( CalendarEventUserConnection::getId )
                          .filter( Objects::nonNull )
                          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
List<CalendarEventUserConnection> connectionsToDelete =
                          existingCalendarEventUserConnections.stream()
                          .filter( idsToDelete::contains )
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(Code untested)

Considering that you use a `HashSet`, this would reduce the complexity to O(M+N) instead of O(MxN)